# Is it correct to call WebServices inside onReceive of BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, web-services, broadcastreceiver, token

I've a BroadcastReciever on a separate class, i register that receiver on one of the activities, and this broadcast receiver trigger when there is an Internet connectivity. Inside `onReceive()` of the receiver, i execute a method for getting token from the server.

But when i gone through the documentation i found that; "*When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed).*"

Please help me with the correct way of doing it.

Comment: create a thread, send a message to thread in OnReceive() and let the thread handle it.

Comment: It's fine bevause onReceive runs on background task

Answer (score 0):

IMO , it is perfectly fine to call a WebService inside the onReceive method of a broadcast receiver. I have done it in many of my applications and till now I have never faced any problem.

Infact in majority of applications, which require frequent updates from server the BroadcastReceiver component is used as the onReceive method runs in the Worker thread/task.

To be on the safe side you can set your WebService timeout to less than 10 secs.Another implementation can be that you can create a background/worker thread, send it a token from the onReceive of your BroadcastReceiver and inside that thread you can call your WebService.

Answer (score 0):

No, The Android System may be kills the your BroadcastReceiver, in case of in-sufficient memory. Because user never or not recently interact with the process of Application.

A process that is currently executing a BroadcastReceiver (that is, currently running the code in its onReceive(Context, Intent) method) **is considered to be a foreground process and will be kept running by the system except under cases of extreme memory pressure.**

That means A Process holds only BroadcastReceiver, then it may be considered as low priority under cases of extreme memory pressure.

This means that for longer-running operations you will often use a Service in conjunction with a BroadcastReceiver to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class)
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(your_url));
    mContext.startService(intent);
```